# Conditional compilation for nullable reference types

Tags: c#, swashbuckle, nullable-reference-types

Is there an existing preprocessor definition that can be used to have conditional compilation based on nullable reference types is enabled or not?

I'm using Swashbuckle to generate swagger.json, and it seems to detect nullability base on argument types. But since we are not ready to use C# 8 yet, we cannot mark the types as 'not null'

What I would like to do is something similar to this (code is from our Swashbuckle IOperationFilter implementatin) :

```
#if !NULLABLE_REFERENCE_TYPES
foreach (var pParam in odataParams)
{
    pParam.Style = ParameterStyle.Simple;

    // Array is nullable, individiual array elements are not
    if (pParam.Schema.Items.Type == "string")
    {
        // Remove when we kan use C# not-nullable feature
        pParam.Schema.Items.Nullable = false;
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: You can have a look at [nullable contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but #nullable requires C# 8 too. Could be that we are a bit paranoid, but we are waiting to use C# 8 until we can use a runtime that supports it full.

Comment: It's fully supported in .NET Core 3.x, classic .NET Framework isn't supported

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find, there does not seem to be a pre-defined compilation constant indicating whether or not NRT is enabled in the current project.

The use of #nullable requires a language version of 8 or above, which might or not be supported depending on which targets you have (anything strictly below standard 2.1, or core 3.1 won't support it).

In our case we opted to use `#if NETSTANDARD2_1_OR_GREATER || NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER`, which works well but does have a shortcoming: if somebody has a net 3.1 or above project with nullable disabled, they'll see warnings. We decided this is fine since all new projects come with NRT enabled by default. If this is not enough, you can combine that conditional compilation with warnings suppression (`#nullable enable/restore`)

Example

```
#if NETSTANDARD2_1_OR_GREATER || NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER
#nullable enable
public string? Foo;
#nullable restore
#else
public string Foo;
#endif
```